# Create folder by book id , download file from batch file, move files into folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10

First, I'll create folder by book id, it works :

And then, Download file from batch file, one URL per line in file.
URL:

- http://url.com/page-1.jpg
- http://url.com/a.mp3
- http://url.com/b.mp3

Here are code and works :

```
import os
import wget

book_id = ["5151","5152","5153"]

for id in book_id:
   directory ="new/"+ str(id)
   if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)


   with open ("%s_url.txt" % id, encoding='utf-8', mode = 'r') as f:
        for url in f.readlines():
            filename = wget.download(url.strip(), out=directory)
            print (filename)
```

5151_url.txt file is not in 5151 folder. I need to move download file into 5151 folder.

I know it could be use `wget.download(url, fullfilename), and fullfilename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
filename = page-1.jpg ..etc.`

Solution: add

```
out=directory)
```

But this will change file name, I don't wanna change file name. How to?

Comment: what does the following print: `url.strip()`

Comment: # filename = wget.download(url.strip()) print (url.strip()) , one url per line .

Comment: can you share its output

Comment: Can you please ensure that your `txt` files contains only urls?

Comment: I think the problem located code line " filename = wget.download(url.strip())" , # this code line, and print (url.strip()) , output is : 1st line, http://url.com/page-1.jpg, 2nd line,http://url.com/a.mp3,  3rd line http://url.com/b.mp3

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM Yes, I'm sure that. Bcz. ''' import wget

with open ("5151_url.txt", encoding='utf-8', mode = 'r') as f:
    for url in f.readlines():
        filename = wget.download(url.strip())
        print (filename) ''' it works fine.

Comment: Oh ! My big mistake. I don't why the url in file has gone. Right now, It works. but I have another problem. @Jeril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import os
import wget
import time

book_id = ["5151","5152","5153"]

for id in book_id:
   directory ="new/"+ str(id)
   if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)


   with open ("new" + "/" + id + "/%s_url.txt" % id, encoding='utf-8', mode = 'r') as f:
        for url in f.readlines():
            time.sleep(4)
            filename = wget.download(url.strip())
            print (filename)
```

Second part is bit modified, and could probably be done litle bit better, but you get an idea. 
And this code reports no problems to me.

I also added `time.sleep(4)` just in case if you have blocking mechanism in place.

And I assume that you have 5151.txt inside the 5151 folder, and others in their respective locations.

Comment: Thank you for your help. ! My big mistake. I don't why the url in file has gone. Right now, It works. 5151_url.txt file is not in 5151 folder. I need to move download file into 515 folder. My code need to fix again.